# How to add new element to double linked list

Tags: c, function, struct

I want to make a function that can add new elements to double linked list in C, but I couldn't do it. Here is code.
New element should have name, group etc. Just explain me how to make name and rest of it I will do by myself.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct inform
{
        char name[20];
        char group[20];
        char form[20];
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        int srok;
} INF_BLOK;

typedef struct list_elem
{
        INF_BLOK inf;
        struct list_elem *next, *prev;
} APTEKA;

APTEKA *head, *tail;


int InputData(INF_BLOK* inf);


int main()
{      

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Find a pen and some paper. Draw a few lists on the paper using boxes for the nodes and arrows for the links. Now using the pen and the paper, try to figure out how to add nodes in different positions in the list. Once you have all that and know what to do, then try to "translate" it to code.

Comment: @Andrey Kompaniets "Just explain me how to make name" - What do you mean?

Comment: @Andrey Kompaniets Take into account that it is a bad idea to declare the variables head and tail as global.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I mean to show me the code with adding element with 'name', if you have time, and i will try to understand the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement a function that inserts an element based on an given index. Note, that i changed your **list_item struct** a bit so that it contains a pointer to your data-elements.

Here is the implementation:

```
/**************************************************************
* Function:     insert_index
* Parameters:   APTEKA* head, INF_BLOK* data, int index
* Return value: Returns NULL on failure, a pointer to the head
*               on success
* Description:  Inserts a APTEKA* element based on an given 
*               index
***************************************************************/
APTEKA* insert_index(APTEKA* head, INF_BLOK* data, int index) {

// Local variable for index
int ind = 1;

APTEKA* new_node = (APTEKA*)malloc(sizeof(APTEKA));
new_node->inf = data;

// Check if head exists, the malloc call was successfull and the index is
// in allowed range
// NOTE: Index for head starts at position 1 
if(head && new_node && index) {

// If index is one, set a new head
if(index == 1) {


    // The previous node is of course NULL
    new_node->prev = NULL;
    new_node->next = head->next;

    if(head->next)
        head->next->prev = new_node;

    head->next = new_node;

    // In a full implementation you need to free the memory for head and the data field in the          
    // structure. free(...)

    // Return a pointer to the new head of the list
    return new_node;
} else {

    APTEKA* current_node = head->next;

    // Loop through all positions before the desired index      
    for(; ind < (index - 1); ++ind)
        current_node = current_node->next;

    new_node->prev = current_node;
    new_node->next = current_node->next;

    if(current_node->next)
        current_node->next->prev = new_node;

    current_node->next = new_node;
    } 
}
else {
    // Return NULL on failure
    return NULL;
}

// Return an pointer to the head
return head;
}
```

**Explanation**:
First the function creates a new node named **new_node** and sets the pointer of the **inf** data field to the given parameter. Before actually inserting i basically check for that everything is right.

I then divide into two cases: first one to replace the head **(index == 1)** and second one is for any other index.

If the head should be replaced i change the dependecies and return a pointer to the newly created node. For any other case i iterate to the element **before** the index and then try to insert it.

When i tested it with this main function, it seemed to work:

```
int main()
{      

/* Only used for testing purposes */

APTEKA* head = (APTEKA*)malloc(sizeof(APTEKA));
APTEKA* first = (APTEKA*)malloc(sizeof(APTEKA));
APTEKA* tail = (APTEKA*)malloc(sizeof(APTEKA));

head->next = first, head->prev = NULL;
first->next = tail, first->prev = head;
tail->next = NULL, tail->prev = first;

/* Information for head node */
INF_BLOK* block_head = (INF_BLOK*)malloc(sizeof(INF_BLOK));
memcpy(block_head->name, "Head", 5); 

/* Information for tail node */
INF_BLOK* block_tail = (INF_BLOK*)malloc(sizeof(INF_BLOK));
memcpy(block_tail->name, "Tail", 5); 

/* Information for first block */
INF_BLOK* block_first = (INF_BLOK*)malloc(sizeof(INF_BLOK));
memcpy(block_first->name, "First", 6);

/* Information for block to add */
INF_BLOK* block_sec = (INF_BLOK*)malloc(sizeof(INF_BLOK));
memcpy(block_sec->name, "Second", 7); 

head->inf = block_head, first->inf = block_first, tail->inf = block_tail;

if(!insert_index(head, block_sec, 2))
    fprintf(stderr, "Error inserting element\n");

APTEKA* element = head;

/* Print out name-data of nodes */
while(element) {
    puts(element->inf->name);
    element = element->next;

}

element = head;

// Freeing everything   
while (element) {
    APTEKA* next = element->next;
    free(element->inf), free(element);
    element = next;
}

return 0;
}
```

Hopefully, my answer gives you the desired insights. If i did something wrong, please correct me :)

NOTE: For this answer i only used the name attribute of your data-item structure. For storing the group, form, etc. you will need another procedure setting those values.